# Passing XML Data in an XML File

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some XML **data** inside an XML file which i want to pass to another application. I have used XMLPullPaser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<node1>
<node2>dd03</node2>
<node3>,17,0,,**<xml><cell>555</cell></xml>**,</node3>
</bintextobj>
```

node 3 contains the data as highlighted. The xml I want to pass as data of xml file. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Are you asking how to exchange data with another application, or how to write a subtree as its own XML file, or something entirely different?

Comment: I want pass the <xml><cell>555</cell></xml> tree to an application. for example as i have written some cell number etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) to store the value.  This will cause the parser to treat the value of node3 like plain text.

```
<node3><![CDATA[,17,0,,**<xml><cell>555</cell></xml>**,]]></node3>
```

Answer (score 0):

write xsl to extract the `<xml>..</xml>` and write into the new xml file which can be passed to the other applications.